# C# How I can make a sum wih Console.Readline

Tags: c#, variables, sum

The idea that I have is:

- Set some variables with its numbers like `int a=15, b=10, c=1`
- Then with the use of `Console.Readline` be able to do the sum, for example a+a+b wrote on the console must show 40.

I tried `Console.WriteLine("sum: {0}",Console.Readline());` I could upload a image with the idea if this it's not enought sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have a read here and format your question:

 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You might want to look into [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) along with the `Dictionary` that @GrantWinney recommends

Comment: @Grant-Winney http://www.subirimagenes.com/otros-errr-9762459.html That's the problem, when I write a+b it' doesn't do the sum. Thank you so much for your answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
var values = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "a", 1 },
    { "b", 2 },
    { "c", 3 }
};
var input = Console.ReadLine().Split('+');
foreach (string variable in input)
{
    sum += values.ContainsKey(variable) ? values[variable] : 0;
}
Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", sum);
```

For example:

```
a+b+c
Sum: 6
```

Comment: wow amazing, like your other code:D thanks, It's somehow like this, but instead of putting values to the letters it will be more like :
Console.ReadLine();
Then I introduce, a+b+c
The result will give me 16, and if I wanted to put a+a+a+a then the result will be 4. Basically I want to sum with the values of my variables.

Comment: awesome that's exactly what I wanted thank you so much:D

Answer (score -1):

Basic procedure if you only wanted to do additions: split the input string and then iterate through said output while adding all the numbers together. Output will be in string format so a cast must be supplied.

Full code:

```
string[] tmp_out = Console.ReadLine().Split('+');
int tmp_sum = 0;
foreach (string tmp_number in tmp_out)
{
    tmp_sum += int.Parse(tmp_number); // consider using TryParse if you are not sure if the input format is correct
}
Console.WriteLine("Sum=" + tmp_sum);
```

If you need further computing power, look into [CSharpCorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/codedom-calculator-evaluating-C-Sharp-math-expressions-dynamica/)

Comment: Thank you so much :D your code helped me a lot to understand more about this!